# jQuery lightbox skipping images only when using arrow navigation

Tags: jquery, gallery, lightbox

I have the same question as [lightbox-0.5 jquery compatibility issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233177/lightbox-0-5-jquery-compatibility-issue/10870806#10870806)

Basically I'm using jQuery Lightbox, and I have a gallery. If I click on a picture the first time and I press the -> arrow key, it goes to the next one. But if I close it and reopen, when I press the -> arrow key it skips one. And if I close it and reopen it, it skips two. And so on.
If you guys wanna see the code it's here: http://pastebin.com/pAigYDCj

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem this way: in the method `_set_image_to_view()` add the line `_disable_keyboard_navigation();` between lines 
`_resize_container_image_box(objImagePreloader.width,objImagePreloader.height);`

and

`objImagePreloader.onload=function(){};`

Thus the entire method is as follows:

```
function _set_image_to_view() { // show the loading
        // Show the loading
        $('#lightbox-loading').show();
        if ( settings.fixedNavigation ) {
            $('#lightbox-image,#lightbox-container-image-data-box,#lightbox-image-details-currentNumber').hide();
        } else {
            // Hide some elements
            $('#lightbox-image,#lightbox-nav,#lightbox-nav-btnPrev,#lightbox-nav-btnNext,#lightbox-container-image-data-box,#lightbox-image-details-currentNumber').hide();
        }
        // Image preload process
        var objImagePreloader = new Image();
        objImagePreloader.onload = function() {
            $('#lightbox-image').attr('src',settings.imageArray[settings.activeImage][0]);
            // Perfomance an effect in the image container resizing it
            _resize_container_image_box(objImagePreloader.width,objImagePreloader.height);
            // for reducing problem with navigation using keyboard (switching some pic at one time)
            _disable_keyboard_navigation();
            // clear onLoad, IE behaves irratically with animated gifs otherwise
            objImagePreloader.onload=function(){};
        };
        objImagePreloader.src = settings.imageArray[settings.activeImage][0];
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been dealing with similar problem a moment ago. Only number of skipped images was random. However I found a solution that worked for me.

Try modifying `_keybord_action` function in `lightbox.js` like this:

```
function _keyboard_action(objEvent) {
        // To ie
        if ( objEvent == null ) {
            keycode = event.keyCode;
            escapeKey = 27;
        // To Mozilla
        } else {
            keycode = objEvent.keyCode;
            escapeKey = objEvent.DOM_VK_ESCAPE;
        }
        // Get the key in lower case form
        key = String.fromCharCode(keycode).toLowerCase();
        // Verify the keys to close the ligthBox
        if ( ( key == settings.keyToClose ) || ( key == 'x' ) || ( keycode == escapeKey ) ) {
            _finish();
        }
        // Verify the key to show the previous image
        if ( ( key == settings.keyToPrev ) || ( keycode == 37 ) ) {
            // If we´re not showing the first image, call the previous
            if ( settings.activeImage != 0 ) {
                _disable_keyboard_navigation();
                settings.activeImage = settings.activeImage - 1;
                _set_image_to_view();
            }
        }
        // Verify the key to show the next image
        if ( ( key == settings.keyToNext ) || ( keycode == 39 ) ) {
            // If we´re not showing the last image, call the next
            if ( settings.activeImage != ( settings.imageArray.length - 1 ) ) {
                _disable_keyboard_navigation();
                settings.activeImage = settings.activeImage + 1;
                _set_image_to_view();
            }
        }
    }
```